# Generating Signed URL for a object in Cloud Storage using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to generate the signed URL for a object in the Cloud Storage using python.

```
import datetime as dt
ini_time_for_now = dt.datetime.now() 
expiration_time = ini_time_for_now + dt.timedelta(minutes = 15) 
print(expiration_time)

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucketname)
blob = bucket.blob(pdffolder) 
blob.upload_from_filename(pdffilename)

url = blob.generate_signed_url('cred.json', bucketname,pdffolder,expiration=expiration_time)
```

I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "entryscript.py", line 18, in <module>
main()
File "entryscript.py", line 13, in main
testpdf(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1])

File "/home/xxxx/GitHub/patch_python/local_test_scripts/patchQuick/Instant_analysis/test.py", line 504, in testpdf

url = blob.generate_signed_url('cred.json', bucketname, 
pdffolder,expiration=expiration_time) 
TypeError: generate_signed_url() got multiple values for argument 'expiration'`
```

Can someone tell me what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try casting the `expiration_time` to a `str` object.

Comment: I tried that, but the same error exists.

Comment: I think you also need the correct permissions [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) you can find the list of the permissions for the Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 4):

Actually your code won't work as you are not using the `generate_signed_url()` method correctly according to its [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.generate_signed_url). In addition I think you're confusing the method [`generate_signed_url`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.generate_signed_url) for a `blob` object with the sample method shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually#python-sample):

> ```
> def generate_signed_url(service_account_file, bucket_name, object_name,
>                        subresource=None, expiration=604800, http_method='GET',
>                        query_parameters=None, headers=None):
> ```

Another thing you should consider is that the expiration date should be in **UTC**.

The following code creates a `Signed URL` from an object already created but you can modify it to fit your requirements:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

#Define the service account key and project id
KEY='path/to/key.json'
PROJECT='PROJECT_ID'

#create a credential to initialize the Storage client
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY)
client = storage.Client(PROJECT,credentials)

#Define your Storage bucket and blob
bucketname = "BUCKET_NAME"
file = "BLOB_NAME"

#Get the time in UTC
ini_time_for_now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

#Set the expiration time
expiration_time = ini_time_for_now + timedelta(minutes = 1) 

#Initialize the bucket and blob
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucketname)
blob = bucket.get_blob(file)

#Get the signed URL
url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=expiration_time)

#Print the URL
print (url)
```

Comment: your right, I actually got confused with the other documentation. I created a service account credential and assigned it the role of a Storage Admin, but I am getting the error that it does have storage,get permission.

Comment: Do you get the error when executing the code? Is it shown when getting the bucket or the file?

Comment: I am getting the error `Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname?projection=noAcl: serviceaccount-name@projectid.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.` while getting the bucket.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a permission issue. I would recommend to check that the service account actually has the right permissions and that you're using that SA in the code. Finally make sure you set the correct project id in the code and that the bucket is in the same project as the SA.

Comment: Doesn't setting the role to Storage Admin suffice? I saw some tutorials and it says Storage admin is the role to be given, since it gives full access to the GCS.

Comment: Yes, with those permissions you're okay. I ran again my code to make sure there was not an issue and it worked perfectly so make sure all the data is set correctly. As mentioned before, check that the bucket is in the same project where the SA was created

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help someone.

1. Browse to API and Services's -> Credentials ->Create Credentials -> Service Account -> give a appropriate service account name and assign Cloud Storage Admin as the role. Download the key (.json file)
2. Browse to the Cloud Storage Bucket, ensure that in the permissions tab of the bucket the service account that was created above is present. If not, click Add Members, add the above created service account and assign the role of Cloud Storage Admin.
3. Use the code given above by @FerVelvet and get the signed URL.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact same error - for some reason the URLs I was getting back to test had the `&` HTML encoded into `&amp;` which was causing this error.

May not be the same issue for you but just in case.